# How to change scene when button is pressed using Sprite Kit and swift 2

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scene

I am new to swift and trying add some extra features after reading this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/66877/how-to-make-a-game-like-candy-crush-part-1. What I want to do is combine with the element of digital pets, kind like the iOS game 'Best Friend'. So first, I add a main scene([picture of main scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfh3K.png)) and several buttons, when button is pressed, the scene would change. Below are the codes I used to achieve it.
MainSceneController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class MainSceneController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var settingButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var storeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var petsButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var levelButton: UIButton!

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mainScene = MainScene(size:CGSize(width: 320, height: 568))
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        mainScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(mainScene)
    }

    @IBAction func changeScene(sender: UIButton) {
        let labelText = sender.titleLabel?.text!
        print(labelText)
        switch (labelText!) {
            case "LevelButton":
                let scene = LevelScene(size:CGSize(width: 320, height: 568))
                let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
                scene.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)
            case "PetsButton":
                let scene = PetsScene(size:CGSize(width: 320, height: 568))
                let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
                scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
                scene.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)
            default:
                break
        }

    }

}

import SpriteKit

class PetsScene: SKScene {

    override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = SKColor.redColor()
        let mylabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        mylabel.text = "PetsScene"
        mylabel.fontSize = 70
        mylabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, 
                                   y: self.frame.size.height / 2)
        self.addChild(mylabel)
    }

}
```

When I pressed the button, the scene do not change. I also use segue to achieve it. But is seems like not what I want. And I have looked for some projects source code, but I cannot find similar one. I would appreciate any advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for either, but it is the method I use to transition between scenes.  I do not use Segues.  I am not sure why, other than that I never bothered to learn how to use them well enough to default to them.  I only rarely use Storyboards, even.  So the below code is an example of how to transition from scene to another just in code.  I usually have a GlobalFunctions.swift file that holds functions that are shared by many classes, the following would be in such a file:

```
func transitionToScene(node: String, sendingScene: SKScene) {

    //println("Entering transition to scene method with \(node) and \(sendingScene.name)")

    let transDur = 1.5
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithColor(sendingScene.backgroundColor, duration: transDur)

    var scene = SKScene()
    switch node {
        case splashSceneString:
            scene = SplashScene(size: sendingScene.size)
        case gameSceneString:
            scene = GameScene(size: sendingScene.size)
        case optionsSceneString:
            scene = OptionsScene(size: sendingScene.size)
        case menuSceneString:
            scene = MenuScene(size: sendingScene.size)
    default:
        if general_debug == true { print("Default should not be reached. No Scene?") }
    }

    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
    sendingScene.view!.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)

}
```

So this func would be called by some event.  For example if you touched a button within your game/app the touchesEnded: function would do something like this:

```
transitionToScene("optionsSceneString", sendingScene: self.scene)
```

Hope this helps somewhat.  Good luck!